# Batch File Closing Unexpectedly?

Tags: batch-file

I am making a game in batch, and at this one point, I have the code detect if you have already done this part of the code before. The reason is because the first time the code executes, it is part of the tutorial, whereas any other time, it executes differently, with more options. However, when it executes the first time, it works perfectly. When it executes the second time, outside of the tutorial, it closes the cmd line.

```
echo You come across a cave.
echo        ########
echo     ######  ######
echo   ###          ######
echo  ###               #####
echo  ##                 #####
echo  ###             #########
echo ###########################
echo.
timeout 2 /NOBREAK>nul
choice /m "Would you like to go in (1), or will you go South (2)?" /c:12 /n
IF errorlevel 2 goto South
IF errorlevel 1 goto Cave

:Cave
timeout 1 /NOBREAK>nul
IF %Exploration% GEQ 2 goto CaveNotFirstTime
```

The first time, it skips the above line and goes on to the rest of the tutorial. When that line later executes, it simply closes cmd line, instead of going on to the other code below. I know that it is at that point because of the timeout command I later added above it. That delay executes before the cmd line closes.

```
echo The cave is dark and scary. You go inside and look around.
set /a Exploration+=1

REM The above line is where it changes the Exploration variable so that the 
REM next time this section executes, it skips past the tutorial.

echo.
echo Your Exploration level went up!
timeout 3 /NOBREAK>nul
choice /m "You found a lump of stone. Would you like to mine it?" /n
IF errorlevel 2 goto TooBad
IF errorlevel 1 goto FirstMineStone

:CaveNotFirstTime
set /a Depth=1
set /a NumberMined=0
echo The cave is damp and musty. In you go!
echo.
set /a ExplorationUp=%RANDOM% %%5
IF ExplorationUp=0 set Exploration+=1 & echo Your exploration went up!
timeout 3 /NOBREAK>nul
set GotoVar=CaveNextLvl
goto CalcCaveRarity
```

Comment: I don't see the `:south` label. Is this the one you are refering to?

Comment: You are missing an equals symbol here: `IF ExplorationUp=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
echo You come across a cave.
echo        ########
echo     ######  ######
echo   ###          ######
echo  ###               #####
echo  ##                 #####
echo  ###             #########
echo ###########################
echo.
timeout 2 /NOBREAK>nul
choice /m "Would you like to go in (1), or will you go South (2)?" /c:12 /n
IF %errorlevel% == 2 goto South
IF %errorlevel% == 1 goto Cave

:Cave
timeout 1 /NOBREAK>nul
IF "%Exploration%" GEQ "2" goto CaveNotFirstTime

echo The cave is dark and scary. You go inside and look around.
set /a Exploration+=1

REM The above line is where it changes the Exploration variable so that the 
REM next time this section executes, it skips past the tutorial.

echo.
echo Your Exploration level went up!
timeout 3 /NOBREAK>nul
choice /m "You found a lump of stone. Would you like to mine it?" /n
IF %errorlevel% == 2 goto TooBad
IF %errorlevel% == 1 goto FirstMineStone

:CaveNotFirstTime
set /a Depth=1
set /a NumberMined=0
echo The cave is damp and musty. In you go!
echo.
set /a ExplorationUp=%RANDOM% %%5
IF "%ExplorationUp%" == "0" set /a Exploration+=1 & echo Your exploration went up!
timeout 3 /NOBREAK>nul
set GotoVar=CaveNextLvl
goto CalcCaveRarity
```

*I am not sure how to explain everything but, i will try*. Assuming you have **`:South :TooBad :FirstMineStone :CalcCaveRarity`** already inside the script.

1. **You aren't using the [Environment Variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) used for `%errorlevel%`**.
2. **Second you did not add proper* `==` or `EQU` to compare
   `%errorlevel%` for the [`If`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) condition**.
3. **You are missing the `""` double quotes to surround your [Variable](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**.
4. **You are also missing `set /a` on the last `if` condition.** Credits To [*Stephan*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan).

Comment: What I provided was actually an excerpt from the rest of the code. The game so far is about 600 lines of code, so I already have the `:South` label used somewhere else. It goes to a mineshaft instead of a cave. However, it has the same problem. Also, when @Protek mentions the Environment Variable used for `%errorlevel%`, I have to ask, is that just the same as using `%errorlevel%` in an `If` statement? Or do I need to use different syntax? I do use the `%errorlevel%` variable in other places in conjunction with `If` statements, but I was under the impression that you could use

Comment: other inputs, such as `If %Blank%==nul`. Also, I thought that you could use `GEQ` (Greater Than or Equal To) instead of `EQU` (Equal To) or `==`. Was I wrong about this? If so, why does that work in other places in the code?

Comment: Also, what string variables are you talking about? All of the variables I used are integer variables and were initialized with the `set /a` command. I thought that a string variable was initialized with the `set /p` command or the `set` command.

Comment: I added the double quotes around the variable assignments like you said, and though it did not fix the problem, I am happy to say that I have noticed some progress. The cmd line still closes after that point, but now, before it does, I see that it executes `echo The cave is dark and scary. You go inside and look around.` It then exits cmd line a split second later, giving me just enough time to see that it printed that before it is gone.

Comment: I left that part out because if you do so, then the accepted inputs default to Y and N instead of 1 and 2, so that would not be the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: Not yet, but I do have an idea that I am going to try. Thanks for your help. Before this, actually didn't know about environment variables, even though I've been doing this for a while. I guess there's always more that you can learn.

Comment: @Protek: you missed `/a` with `set Exploration+=1`